# GetCellDescent() GetEmHeight() в wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

есть многострочных текстовый контрол на винформах, необходимо переписать его на контрол RichTextBox wpf.
у контрола есть метод динамически рассчитывающий его размер в котором используются методы:

```
_editor.Font.FontFamily.GetCellDescent(FontStyle.Regular)
_editor.Font.FontFamily.GetEmHeight(FontStyle.Regular)
_editor.Font.Height
```

в контроле исп System.Drawing.FontFamily, в RichTextBox же исп System.Windows.Media.FontFamily и ничего похожего на эти методы нет. подскажите чем можно заменить эти методы для получения размеров?

Comment: так в WPF же размер указывается в относительных единицах, это и шрифтов касается. От физического разрешения экрана не зависит. Поправьте если ошибаюсь. Или вам нужно менять размер в зависимости от размера шрифта выбранного пользователем?

Comment: **Или вам нужно менять размер в зависимости от размера шрифта выбранного пользователем** - именно. после инициализации контрола, надо задать ему размер в зависимости от размера указанного шрифта, чтобы, например, в высоту влазило 5 строк шрифтом 12.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9266288/5796587 посмотрите, возможно это то что вам нужно